# C++'s Class Problems

Tags: c++, class

I am asking you a question from the C ++ class. When you look at the
 C + + course videos, why are they using the voids(functions) that people use outside of class. Can someone explain this to me?

example:

```
void example::example1()
{
// code stuff
}
```

Comment: It seems that you are confused about class methods declared inside the class and defined outside the class,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you can use voids when you dont have anything to return. So they use void because they are functions who do some functions with members of these classes.

Or if you refer to syntax, whats behind the :: thats the class, and it's a way to organize your code

Answer (score 0):

Trying looking into what a class is used for. How different classes can be used within an application, how classes can extend or inherit other properties within another class to minimise repetitive code.

Also if you find yourself getting confused throughout a tutorial or course videos, refer back to the material before. I still get confused with video however I've found looking back to the previous videos or even finding other videos will help. media such as books or youtube video are goldmines for knowledge in these areas.

Also another good tip regarding books, *buy physical copies; use online pdf sites as these are the material most programmers look for.

Hope this helps...

*Edit: Try not to buy physical copies where possible as there will put you back a few pennies

Comment: `good tip regarding books, don't buy physical copies` this is pretty controversial

Comment: True I understand we must give the writers credit where due and give them capital in their pockets however, if you can get the material free why should we pay, especially when these books cost in excess of 60.99 at times

Comment: There you go changed it for you SingerOfTheFall, admitting I was wrong in certain areas